# Single identity with partitioned client and scope configuration

Tags: identityserver3

## Problem

Lets say an organisation requires a single user identity for all its consumer (non-staff) users.  The organisation is large and has many business units that operate their own consumer facing applications but all of which require the use of the single IDP's users.

Each business unit must be able to control their own application configuration with the IDP and have no control over any other BU's application configuration.

All consumer identities are created as part of the organisation's user provisioning process to validate who the person is.  There will be no self-registration.

### Option 1

My first thought is to have separate identity servers, one for each business unit.  This at least provides the configuration separation.  Then have a single organisation IDP for consumer users only.

Each BU-specific IDP would support logins from the organisation IDP, either by selection from the BU IDP login screen or immediate redirect to the org IDP if the BU specific app required it to do so.

This is sort of multi-tenancy albeit not in a single service offering.  It does mean each BU manages their user identities and app configuration and allows login via the singular org identity (plus local BU IDP account).  Also, admin (some staff) users could login via a local BU account or the company AAD identity if so configured.

### Options 2

Have a single organisation identity server and provide a configuration api/ui to support partitioning of the client and scope data.  This means each BU would be restricted to only their app identity config data but would allow all users to consume all apps without having many local accounts (one in each BU IDP).

Each app would have to have some sort of naming convention for scopes to not clash with scopes used in another BU's apps.  Something like _mywebapi.

My question is should option 1 be the architecture choice over option 2 where many business units want control over their own token-based apps but want to consume a single user identity?  Or are there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two. You can have a central token service to achieve the SSO and all it does it issue a unique id for the user to all of the business units. Then the business units have their own token service that allows them to control access and configuration for their apps and apis.

To wire the two token services together, you have the business unit token service federate to the central token service.

Comment: Thanks Brock.  Does the business unit token service still require a local user account to manage registered external logins?  I'm assuming federation here means external login but if I'm off track can you direct me to an example perhaps?

Comment: Both would have a record in the DB for the user, yes. The central one would have credentials, the business unit one would just have the unique id from the central IdP.